# Javascript Date Generation programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have 2 Date Objects. One is **from** and another contains **to**.
The date format used is `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

My problem is that I am using a charting tool and I have to map dates
on charting tool based on data.
So I need to divide this From and To Date based on data
if I have a selection from `2015-10-9 to 2015-12-23`

I can break this down into n number of selection. Usually data length to be represented on x axis is 10 at max.

Comment: What i understand is you want to divide a range (between start and end date) by a unit values and represent some associated data.. is it right??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's working code.

```js
function test(){
var a=new Date(2015, 00, 01);
var b=new Date(2015, 05, 07);
ret=divideDates(a, b);

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="Start Date was: "+a.toString()+"<br/><hr />";
for(var key in ret){
 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="<br />"+ret[key];
}
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="<br/><hr />End Date was: "+b.toString();

}
function divideDates(startDate, endDate){
 var thediff=endDate-startDate;
 var thetenth=thediff/10;
 var resp = [];
 for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
 var toAdd=thetenth*i;
 resp[i]=new Date(startDate.getTime()+toAdd);
 }
 return resp;
}
```

and here is a test HTML page i used (obv.ly call the js file "func.js"):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="func.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:test();" value="testIT">
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can even tell the difference in days adding this to the end of the test function:
tmp=b-a;
diffDays=Math.round(tmp/86400000);
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="<br/><hr />the difference in milliseconds is: "+tmp;
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="<br/>that are "+diffDays+" days ";

Comment: thanks. i will give it a try today and would let u know. thanks for yr help